# Rails relationships with different column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a demo app to try to learn RoR, and I'm confused by how to handle a situation where there's two users linked with a non-standard column name.

I've built a `User` table, an `Offer` table and a `Contract` table. If a user creates an offer, it's simple to link the user id to the offer, using `belongs_to :user` in the `Offer` model. This obviously connects the `Offer.user_id` column to the `User.id` column.

However once an offer becomes a contract, then there's a `Contract.buyer_id` and `Contract.seller_id`, both of which point to a `User.id`-- but how can I specify that in the `Contract` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "buyer_id"
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "seller_id"
end
```

you don't have to mention the `foreign_key` explicitly since rails will look for a column with `<association_name>_id`, I think that it makes it easier to read if you specify it explictly